# How to make WPF windows on Top of VSTO Application only?

Tags: c#, wpf, vsto

I am developing a VSTO application with a WPF Window added to the Application.
I want to make WPF window to stay on top only for the Excel file that it was triggered from.
I made WPF window TopMost=True and it is staying on top of all other applications running
Then I tried this

```
mw.Owner = new WindowWrapper((System.IntPtr)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd);
```

But it is giving an error. Can someone help here please

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot set Owner property to a
>   Window that has not been shown previously.'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050426/wpf-always-on-top

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861406/possible-to-cast-active-microsoft-word-window-to-wpf-window

Comment: Thank you, Andy. This is exactly what I was looking for